# Is there a bold italic \sigma and a sans serif bold italic \sigma?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, bold, italic, sans-serif

And they look differently?

I'm trying to typeset iso conform (vectors bold italic and tensors sans serif bold italic).

Mechanical stress `$\sigma$` is a tensor, but I also want to typeset the normal stress, which is the tensor multiplied by the unit normal `$\mathbf n$` and hence, a vector as well.

I tried `bm` (results in serif bold `\sigma`) or isomath (error *font shape OML/ptm/bx/it undefined*).

Comment: Is `\usepackage{bm}...\begin{document}$\bm\sigma$` what you want? Or how exactly do you expect `\sigma` to appear?

Comment: I found this on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma#Character_Encodings):  (mathematical bold italic small sigma) and  (mathematical sans-serif bold italic small sigma). $\bm \sigma$ yields a very bold σ, but I don't know what it is exactely.

Comment: The comprehensive reference http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf is a very useful resource that has many varieties of greek symbols, including bold. Whether there is one that fits your need is to be determined.

Comment: the comprehensive reference lists `\upsigma` (serif, upright), but no sans-serif.

Comment: I think the answer offered by @andrew is very nice, but I'm still a bit reluctant to switch all my documents to lualatex (no stable release yet).

Answer (score 3):

If you have the option of using `lualatex` then `unicode-math` provides access to such characters:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatextra,lualatex-math}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,sans-style=italic]{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{Tex Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont{Tex Gyre Cursor}
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}
\( \sigma \mathbf{\sigma} \mathbfsf{\sigma} \)

\( \psi \mathbf{\psi} \mathbfsf{\psi} \)
\end{document}
```

`Tex Gyre Termes Math` is quite new, an older font is `Tex Gyre Pagella Math`, the name has just changed from `TG Pagella Math`:

[image: Sample pagella]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatextra,lualatex-math}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,sans-style=italic]{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont{Tex Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont{Tex Gyre Cursor}
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
\( \sigma \mathbf{\sigma} \mathbfsf{\sigma} \)

\( \psi \mathbf{\psi} \mathbfsf{\psi} \)
\end{document}
```

Alternatively there are the `XITS` fonts, where the distinction is less clear:

[image: Sample XITS]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatextra,lualatex-math}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,sans-style=italic]{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
\( \sigma \mathbf{\sigma} \mathbfsf{\sigma} \)

\( \psi \mathbf{\psi} \mathbfsf{\psi} \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried compiling this with lualatex, but for this I'd need to install some more fonts. I'm considering doing this in the future.

Comment: I have added a couple of older font suggestions.  All the fonts are in the latest texlive.

Comment: thanks!!! using `\setmathfont{TG Pagella Math}` works in my latex environment!!